# MySQL sorting: why is "5x" after "11x"?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a table in MYSQL with a column called league.

When I try to sort the values using this query I cant get it to sort correctly.

```
SELECT DISTINCT (
t.league
)
FROM teams t
GROUP BY t.league
ORDER BY t.league ASC
```

However with this I get:

```
11a12
13
14
15
16a17
5a7
8a10
```

it looks like it sorts all of them correctly except the last two

Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the column must be of a string type and `5` comes AFTER `11`. You might consider changing those fields (which seem to be multivaluated) into 2 separate numeric fields (or even 3 if that `a` value makes any difference)

Comment: Yes, because in a meritocracy, being 22 seconds earlier is _much_ more important than the quality of the answer :-) <-- note the smiley.

Comment: That hurts :'( <-- note the tear

Answer (score 5):

No, they are sorted lexicographically rather than numerically:

```
11a12
13
14
15
16a17
5a7        # 5 is greater than 1
8a10
```

If you want to sort them numerically, you can use things like:

```
order by (t.league + 0)
order by cast (t.league, int)
```

but I'm not sure how they'll handle the non-numerics in the field. You may want to look into using [the `lpad` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad):

```
order by lpad (t.league, 20, '0')
```

which will pad the field to a specific size by prefixing it with `0` characters.

Just keep in mind that per-row functions rarely scale well so, if you want to maintain performance as the table grows in size, you may want to do something like split the column into components, making the numeric ones non-text. Depending on your specific circumstances, that may or may not work.

Comment: So how can this be sorted based on the "leading integer" in said string? Or how could the data be adjusted to allow this?

Comment: You can use the `ABS()` function to order numerically, but that wont work if the data has characters inside it.